What should I do if I experience discharge after using the bathroom?
After using the bathroom there is sometimes left over urine that comes out after I leave the bathroom. I try my best to get it all out but sometimes i get feeling that when I am walking around it’s still leaking.
Lately there is other liquid coming out as well after using the restroom (idk if its semen or something else but it looks similar to semen), i don’t know how to stop it or what to do.
What’s the ruling as far as praying salah and making wudhu. Do i have to change my clothes every-time this happens?
